# Pass pattern based on current word to command in vim

Tags: regex, vim

I'm trying to get ctags playing nicely with ruby class and method definitions. I now have a a ctags file being generated which works such that if I do a visual select of something like:

```
Module::Class
```

from a full line which looks like:

```
::Module::Class.new(something)
```

And then press `ctrl`+`]` ctags will go to the correct file. I'm now trying to create a keyboard shortcut which will automatically:

- Select based on the current word forwards until it reaches either a space, a `.` or a line end
- Select based on the current word backwards until it reaches either the start of the line or a space
- Exclude from the selection the first `::`
- Pass the result into the vim command `:ta:` to load the relevant tag

Currently unsure and cannot find information on:

- How to perform the selection around the current word
- How to pass a "selection" like this into a Ruby command

Answer (score 1):

All you want to do is possible in normal mode:

```
viw/ \|\.\|$/e<CR><C-]>
```

to select forward.

```
wgev? \|^[^(::)]\|^::.?e<CR><C-]>
```

to select backwards.

Of course you can map the commands to your needs.